# Don't know how to use nom's dbg_dmp

Tags: rust, nom

I have a parser setup where I've injected `dbg_dmp` to the best of my ability:

```rust
permutation((
        check_eye_color,
        check_passport_id,
        check_birth_year,
        check_issue_year,
        check_expiry_year,
        check_hair_color,
        check_height,
        dbg_dmp(check_cid, "cid"),
    ))(input)
```

This gives me:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(&str,)>` closure, found `impl Fn<(&[u8],)>`
```

No clue why or how to resolve this.

Comment: Looks like your `check_cid()` function does not have the right signature

Comment: Without the `dbg_dmp` it does fit in there, so how does it not have the right signature?

Comment: https://docs.rs/nom/6.0.1/nom/fn.dbg_dmp.html

Comment: `where F: Fn(&'a [u8]) -> IResult<&'a [u8], O, E>`

Comment: That would seem like it, but wouldn't it then be kinda useless? It is implied here that you can generically use them to debug your stuff: https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/master/doc/error_management.md

Comment: Also as a beginner I can't read those function signatures to save my life. I find them absurdly unhelpful.

Comment: Sorry, can't help anymore, I'm missing something as well (never used `dbg_dmp()`)

Comment: It could be that the debugging options are only for macro nom and not for new nom. The `nom_trace` crate definitely seems to be.